# Why do the `tkinter.ttk.Notebook` tabs get thinner and thinner?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I am using a `tkinter.ttk.Notebook` and the tabs seem to get thinner with time. How do I overcome this? Is there a possibility to specify a uniform width for each tab?

[image]

I use this code to add a tab:

```
notebook.add(game.frame, text=game.name, underline=0, sticky=tkinter.NS)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to set a uniform width for each tab, but it seems that the tab width problem is style dependent:

- with style "alt" the tab name SEVEN is partially hidden:
  [image: notebook with alt style]
- with style "clam" it is fully visible:
  [image]

Here is how to change style of the whole window:

```
sty = ttk.Style() 
sty.theme_use(theme_name)
```

To get the list of all theme names: `sty.theme_names()`.

You can get more information on ttk styles here http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-theme-layer.html.

Comment: Thanks, it's great. I noticed that the problem only arises in Window's native styles. Another thing, are these styles limited to the few or are there others available on the internet?