# tkinter notebook python tab titles overlapping

Tags: python, tkinter

Quick question all,

My (very simple) tkinter GUI program:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    test = ttk.Notebook(root)
    test.grid()
    tab1 = ttk.Frame(test)
    tab2 = ttk.Frame(test)
    tab3 = ttk.Frame(test)

    test.add(tab1, text="1")
    test.add(tab2, text="Tab Two")
    test.add(tab3, text="Tab Three")

    root.title("CONTROL PANEL")
    root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Why is the second tab being overlapped by the third?

Initially, i thought it was a grid option that i had missed but i could not find the relevant option.
Thanks guys.

**EDIT:** This occurs when tab 1 has a short title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do the \`tkinter.ttk.Notebook\` tabs get thinner and thinner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243547/why-do-the-tkinter-ttk-notebook-tabs-get-thinner-and-thinner)

Comment: part of the problem may be that your tabbed notebook is simply too small. You didn't configure it to expand with the window, so it starts out so small that there's not enough room for the tabs. Are you intentionally wanting the notebook to be very small?

Comment: I've tried creating the notebook that is larger (with larger frames in each tab) and the same thing occurs unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the following themes:
('**winnative**', 'clam', '**alt**', '**default**', 'classic', '**vista**', '**xpnative**')

When either a 'clam' or 'classic' style is used, the tab titles fit. i.e.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    test = ttk.Notebook(root)
    test.grid()
    tab1 = ttk.Frame(test)
    tab2 = ttk.Frame(test)
    tab3 = ttk.Frame(test)

    # added code to change style
    s = ttk.Style(test)
    s.theme_use('STYLE AS ABOVE')
    ############################

    test.add(tab1, text="1")
    test.add(tab2, text="Tab Two")
    test.add(tab3, text="Tab Three")

    root.title("CONTROL PANEL")
    root.mainloop()
```